Downloading larger file in flutter using retrofit api call?
I'm trying to download  some media or file from backend using retrofit api calling in flutter. But after  sometime it show out of memory and default get connection  time out.there is some solution using @Streaming hut I dint find it in retrofit .
I tried using retrofit but it is limited to certain size
